# bind the same context to multiple functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a series of Promises that I've written inside of a class:

```
class Executor {

    someFunction(){
        return Promise.resolve(function(){
            console.log(this.name);
        });
    };

    someOtherFunction(){
        return Promise.resolve(function(){
            console.log(this.date);
        });
    };

    execute(){
        let {someFunction, someOtherFunction} = this;
        this.name = "John";
        this.date = "Saturday";
        someFunction=someFunction.bind(this)
        someFunction().then(someOtherFunction.bind(this));
    }

}
```

that I then invoke by instantiating the class and running the `execute` method:

```
var e = new Executor;
e.execute();
```

Is there a better way to bind the context of the class to multiple functions rather than writing multiple `bind()` statements?

Comment: Context caching. `class Executor { var self = this; someFunction() { console.log(self.name); // Use self now. ...`

Comment: you could at least write a helper function to cut down on repetition. it's good to keep functions pure via `this`, so the bind() is a good mechanism, it's just long-winded.

Comment: you can also just use fat arrows in ES6, which does that bind stuff for you, more or less...

Comment: why are you working so hard? `this.someFunction().then(() => this.someOtherFunction)` - simple, single line, no fuss.

Comment: (P.S. you code is very broken - `someFunction` declared twice, used as if the function is called, but really isn't...)

Comment: whoops, hopefully fixed now

Comment: WTH? I'm pretty sure you did *not* mean to fulfill your promises with function objects and never call these log statements, did you?

Comment: nope, what's the correct edit here?

Comment: Are you OK with polluting Promise.prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need destructing here, it only complicates things, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```js
'use strict';
class Executor {
  someFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.name);
        resolve();
      }, 250);
    });
  };

  someOtherFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.date);
        resolve();
      }, 250);
    });
  };

  execute() {
    this.name = "John";
    this.date = "Saturday";
    this.someFunction()
      .then(() => this.someOtherFunction())
      .then(() => { console.log('done!'); });
  }
}

let e = new Executor();
e.execute();
```

Note that your `Promise` usage was broken.

Comment: what if I want both functions to be promises?

Comment: You can, but it's a dangerous anti-pattern (see link in answer).

Comment: @fox - still looking for an answer? (what's not clear?)

Comment: @Amit: No use of the promise construction antipattern. In fact he doesn't use the `Promise` constructor at all.

Comment: @Bergi - if `someFunction` & `someOtherFunction` both return `new Promise(...)`, and `someOtherFunction` is invoked within the `then(...)` of `someFunction` - then it *is* the anti-pattern, and that's what fox asked about.

Comment: @Amit: The OP uses `Promise.resolve`, not `new Promise`.

Comment: @Bergi I really don't understand why we're in this argument but... *what if I want both functions to be promises* is the question asked by OP regarding my answer where `new Promise` is used.

Comment: @Amit: OK, maybe I was just confused… whatever.

Comment: so what's the correct pattern in this case if I'm not supposed to chain promises like this?

Comment: @fox - every asynchronous function should return a Promise (like `someFunction` in my answer), and synchronous functions should not deal with Promises at all. Chaining is simple as in `execute`.

Comment: @Amit: so, in my OP I was looking to chain two async functions (your code here has one aysnc and one sync function). That makes me think that my error is in the way that I am invoking these with promises and not returning the promises inside of a wrapping function. What is the correct way to invoke two async promises in a chain together, one after the other?

Comment: @fox - your code contains invalid use of the `Promise` constructor (see `someFunction` in this answer for proper use). Other then that, you can repeat this pattern for both functions, and in `execute` either bind or wrap with arrow function like I showed.

Comment: @Amit: can I trouble you to update your code above with two async functions? after you do that, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Amit: also, is it correct to be invoking the functions without binding the `this` context?

Comment: @fox - changed code. you don't have to bind if you wrap with an arrow function - see code.

Comment: @Amit: do you need to bind `this` to `someFunction()`?

Comment: @fox - I don't see why (or where to be more accurate). The call is made using `this` --> `this.someFunction()`. What would you bind?

Comment: @Amit: in my original code above, I bound `this` to `someFunction()` before invoking it. In your code, do you have access to `name` and `date` inside of `someFunction()`?

Comment: @fox - you don't need to bind anything.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to bind the context of the class to multiple functions rather than writing multiple `bind()` statements?

There are difference ways of referring to the value of `this`, or bind a function (see [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)), but a shorthand to bind multiple functions at once does *not* exist.

Answer (score 1):

This approach may or may not thrill you. We define a `context` method on `Promise` to attach a context to the promise, and a `thenWithContext` method to do a `then` with automatic binding of the handlers passed in.

```
Object.defineProperties(Promise.prototype, {

  context: { value: function(context) { this.context = context; return this; } },

  thenWithContext: { value: function(resolve, reject) {
    return this.then(
      (...args) => typeof resolve === 'function' && resolve.call(this.context, ...args),
      (...args) => typeof reject  === 'function' && reject.call (this.context, ...args)
    ).context(this);
  } }

});
```

Usage:

```
execute() {
  this.someFunction() . context(this) . thenWithContext(this.someOtherFunction);
}
```